# Why does appending list to list in python causes weird behaviour?

Tags: python

There are some things about how lists work in python that i dont understand.

This is the python code:

```
n=int(input())
m=int(input())
k=1
a=[]
temp = []
for i in range(n):
    temp.clear()
    for j in range(m):
        temp.append(k)
        k = k+1
    print(temp)
    a.append(temp)
print(a)
```

and this is my output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
[13, 14, 15, 16]
[[13, 14, 15, 16], [13, 14, 15, 16], [13, 14, 15, 16], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

so why does my matrix have row that are the same as the last one when i clearly appended other values. What am I missing? I run into this problem every once in while and I can not read enouth documentation. So there it is folk, help anyone?

Comment: `a.append(temp)` doesn't make a copy of `temp`, so you keep appending the same list every time, and each time through the loop you add a number to it.

Comment: move `temp = []` inside the first `for` and remove `temp.clear()`.  The former starts a new list while the latter empties the same list over and over.